# Gossip in Physics

Tags: quantum-field-theory, supersymmetry

Given, $M_4 = \Sigma \times C$, 
      How do you get an effective theory by studying maps
$\Sigma \rightarrow M_4$ .
    Technically, the physics in one manifold is supposed to gossip about the overall affairs of people in the entire manifold at least up to a certain limit.
    To be direct I am trying to know how the algebra bundles come about as a twist in $\sigma$ models. I am sure my question is not well posed, as usual feel free to edit it.

Comment: Seriously? There's a gossip term in maths?

Comment: What "effective theory" do you want to obtain here? A theory on $\Sigma$ from a theory on $M_4$? Who calls this "gossip"? Which "algebra bundles" are you taking about? A sigma model is for instance superstring theory for maps $\Sigma\to M_10$, but the target space is not forced to be written as the product of $\Sigma$ and something else. I'm really not sure what you're asking.